# Throw exception with inner exception in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I am trying to send an exception over the WCF wire but can't figure out what I have done wrong.
I am following the [guidance of Oleg Sych](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649840.aspx) but to no avail.

What I get back is `The requested service, 'net.tcp://mymachine/myservicepath/MyService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.`.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISystemInfoService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(MyException))]
    void DoThrowException(string message);
}

//[ServiceContract]  // <- the culprit
public class SystemInfoService : ISystemInfoService
{
    public void DoThrowException(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new MyException( "MyMessage" );
        }
        catch (MyExceptionexc)
        {
            throw new FaultException<MyException>(exc);
        }
    }
}

// The custom Exception resides in an common assembly reachable from both server and client.
[Serializable]
public class MyException: Exception
{
...
}
```

TIA

Comment: So, did you `See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information` ?

Comment: Good spotting @nvoigt - I am ashamed to answer that I had not. When I checked Event viewer->Custom views->Adminstrative events I found `... Contract inheritance can only be used among interface types.  If a class is marked with ServiceContractAttribute, it must be the only type in the hierarchy with ServiceContractAttribute...` which was clearly the culprit. I have updated the original code to show this.

Comment: @nvoigt - Do answer with an instruction on how to get to "the server's diagnostic trace logs" and I will happily give you your well earned points.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try handling the exception with a datacontract class instead of serializable exception?

```
[DataContract]
public class MyExceptionClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public Exception Exc { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ISystemInfoService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(MyExceptionClass))]
    void DoThrowException(string message);
}

public class SystemInfoService : ISystemInfoService
{
    public void DoThrowException(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("MyMessage");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            var data = new MyExceptionClass { Exc = exc };
            throw new FaultException<MyExceptionClass>(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my first try and it failed. It is probably a perfectly good way; I just how to figure out how.

Comment: Generally you don't want to expose the actual exception (and the stack trace) to the client using your WCF service. You should send just meaningful error codes and messages.